# How to use values from another object within the same class for a getter function?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, getter

I can't find an answer to what is likely a simple problem: how can I use values from one object to set the values in another object within the same class, using a getter function?

I'm new to JS and can't think of another way to reference the values I need other than using `this`, but `this` in this case refers to the object that's calling the getter. I need to reference the other object in the class. I also cannot pass in arguments to a getter function as far as I understand them.

Also, I recognize there are other less dynamic ways of implementing this. My original code just set `maxDamage: this.vitals.strength * 2`, but then I'd need a method to refresh this variable if `vitals.strength` changes. I figured that using a getter function might be a more dynamic, concise way of doing this.

In the code below, I'm trying to set `attackStats.maxDamage` equal to a calculation using `vitals.strength` such that each time I get the maxDamage the getter returns something like `vitals.strength * 2`. **Also, `maxDamage` needs to be dynamic because `vitals.strength` will change often! I'd rather not have to manually refresh it each time this changes.**

```
class Warrior {

  vitals = {
    maxHealth: 120,
    health: 120,
    strength: 10,
  }

  attackStats = {

    type: 'Sword Swing',

    get maxDamage () {
      return [some calculation using vitals.strength]
    }
}
```

I think I could solve the problem by merging the objects into one larger object so that `this` works as intended, but I want to keep them separate.

How can I pass access vitals.strength from the getter function?

Comment: Inside of the attackStats object, you could pass in ```maxDamage: this.vitals.strength*2```

Comment: @GianlucaFuoco Thanks for the suggestion. This is the setup I originally had, but I'd like the property to be dynamic so that if `vitals.strength` changes then so do `maxDamage`. I could use a method to refresh `maxDamage`, but I figured there must be something more concise using a getter function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly do you ask.
But in the class is a constructor missing...

I made an example for you here, maybe it helps to understand how the construction method works.

```js
class Warrior {
  constructor ({maxHealth, stregth}) {
    this.vitals = {
      maxHealth: maxHealth,
      health: maxHealth,
      strength: stregth,
    }
    
    this.attackStats = {
      type: 'Sword Swing',
      damage: 2,
      maxDamage: null,
    }
    
    this.setMaxDamage()
  }
  
  setMaxDamage () {
    this.attackStats.maxDamage = this.vitals.strength * this.attackStats.damage;
  }   
}

let orcWarrior = new Warrior({maxHealth:120, stregth:10});
console.log(orcWarrior.attackStats.maxDamage);
```